# Having different pages but same route for mobile devices in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

Is it possible to have different razor page files or views, with same routes for Razor Pages?

In classic ASP.NET MVC, controller could do a check like

```
if(Request.Page.IsMobileDevice())
   return View("Mobile");
else
   return View("Desktop");
```

Is this approach somewhat possible in RazorPages, such as changing RootPages folder per request or something similar?

Comment: You can look into implementing your own view engine that could rewrite the path of a view

Comment: There is no equivalent to IsMobileDevice in ASP.NET Core. The recommended approach is to use responsive design that takes account of the device size and adapts the display accordingly, rather than creating multiple versions of the same site.

Comment: @MikeBrind why do you think it is not possible to add IsMobileDevice via service. We are already using it on several projects.
Not all websites are suitable for responsive web design. Some are much more maintainable if views are separated, especially for sites with a lot of google advertising, where hiding ad is against google policy

Comment: I didn't say that it is not possible to implement your own IsMobileDevice and register it as a service. Your question appears to compare "classic" MVC with .NET Core (Razor Pages). I responded purely to that comparison.